# How and where do I learn philosophy?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy

I am very new to philosophy, in what ways can I gain deeper knowledge about the subject itself and explore all the branches and truly understand what philosophy exactly is?

Comment: A lot of reading.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Stay away from crazies too. They like to do semantic infiltration to undermine and create strawmen arguments.